# Meteor.call all methods return as not found

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I'm running a server that has a couple of server side methods deployed using Meteor-up.

Every time I try and call a method from the client (or through DDP) the method returns a 404 error with Method not found.

I know that the methods exist and can be called from the server side since I am using this to test both:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(Object.keys(Meteor.server.method_handlers).sort());
    Meteor.call('b', function(err, data){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Which returns:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'getCurrentTime' ]
undefined
Method call successful
```

when called.

Here are the method declarations.

**`/server/methods.js`**

```
Meteor.methods({
    getCurrentTime: function(){
        return new Date();
    },
    a: function(){
        return "b";
    },
    b: function(){
        return "Method call successful";
    }
});
```

When I run it locally, everything works as expected. I'm currently attempting to run it through Meteor directly to see if it still happens.

EDIT:

Added method declarations as per request

I tested it running on the server using the `meteor` command. Everything worked as expected.

Comment: could you show your method definition on the server, too?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Method calls are added

Comment: and what is the problem? you call `b` and it executes fine. does the same call not work from the client, is that what you are saying?

Comment: @ChristianFritz The method call works on the server but always returns "method not found" on the client.

Comment: are you sure `Meteor.server.method_handlers` isn't the problem? other than that it's a 100% usual method call

Comment: I'm as sure as I can be. I really think it might be something to do with the mup deployment. I ran it on the server that its deployed on and locally and the calls work exactly as expected from there. Its only when its deployed using Meteor-Up that it seems to have this problem...

Comment: well, in the current form of your question you are essentially asking "do methods work in deployment". So the answer to that is obviously yes, and contradicts your experience. So it needs to be something about your setup. For that, though, there simply isn't enough information in your question. Do you get the same behavior when making the call from the client console?